# Find user from mention (Discord.js, Slash Commands)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I basically have a value and I want my bot to find that user in my guild. I'm trying to do this with slash commands!

```
//This gets the guild that the slash command was used in
const guild = bot.guilds.cache.get(interaction.guild_id)

//This is for example, the content from the slash command would be like this
let value = `<@!123456789012345678>`

//I tried this but it doesn't work
//This is what I need to know
let userR = guild.members.cache.find(member => member === value)
```

If  someone knows how to do this then please let me know. Thanks! (Also I just got stackoverflow so I'm kinda new)

Comment: Extract the id from the mention via regex, then use `guild.members.cache.get(id)`

Comment: Ok I will try that.

Comment: I was having issues trying to get regex to work but I was able to do it just by replacing the <@! and > with ``. But thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
interaction.guild.members.cache.get("your_user_id_here")
```

with the id as a string.
To get the id you can add a number or menion option to your slash command, and then use

```
interaction.options.getMember("your_option_id_here").id
```

If you don't know how to use options you can read the official guide [here](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/replying-to-slash-commands.html#command-options).

In a full code it would look like this:

```
function execute(interaction){
    //Defines the guild
    const guild = bot.guilds.cache.get(interaction.guild_id)

    //Gets the id of the member option
    let value = interaction.options.getMember("option_id").id;

    //Gets the member as a GuildMember object
    let member = guild.members.cache.get(value)
}
```

Hope i could help!
PS: To all guys who complain about spoonfeeding im sorry but i was to lazy to explain it without it!